How can I improve the performance of my ANTLR4 generated Parser(for java grammar, in C++)?
The antlr4 version is the latest, at the time of posting, 4.13.2, compiled from source.
I am using the java8-grammar provided by the grammars-v4 antlr repo
I intend to parse large projects for static analysis purposes and it requires a parser implemented in C++. I turned to ANTLR4 for the parser to avoid writing one by hand as the java grammer is intensely recursive, verbose and heavy on context.
The parser generated feels abysmal in performance, taking seconds to parse medium files and minutes for this specific one openapi-generator-java-class, specifically one and a half minutes. It is a 2K LoC file but this order of size feels too much. A 1.2K Loc File oas-gen-java-class takes around 25.5 seconds. The measurements were done using a QElapsedTimer (along with sitting and waiting for the complete parse to finish which takes a lot).
The code i've written to use the parser is the simplest possible.
 stream.open(javaFile);
 QElapsedTimer timer;
 timer.start();
 ANTLRInputStream input(stream);
 Java8Lexer lexer(&input);
 BufferedTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
 Java8Parser parser(&tokens);
 tree::ParseTree *tree = parser.compilationUnit();
 std::cout << "Parsing time: " << timer.elapsed() << "ms .\n";

My questions are:

What steps would you take to improve its performance?
For this use case, Parsing java code in C++, is there any alternative I should try out(libraries,parser generators etc. etc.)?

Things I have tried so far(will edit this if i try something new):

Using BufferedTokenStream instead of CommonTokenStream
Linking antlr statically (using the .a file instead of the .so file, with -fpic)


Sound like you are using a debug build, not a release build.

I will go try it with a release build thank you for the suggestion, but is the difference that huge between debug and release builds?

It is not a difference between debug and release! The problem is that the grammar is ambiguous when directly translated from the JLS. Don't use java8. Use instead java. It parses DefaultGenerator.java in 1s in C#. You can still use java8 if you insist, but you need to save the parse tree to avoid reparsing.

I am getting this, probably doing something wrong here with the parser generation process.
line 1:7 extraneous input ' ' expecting {'module', 'open', 'requires', 'exports', 'opens', 'to', 'uses', 'provides', 'with', 'transitive', 'var', 'yield', 'record', 'sealed', 'permits', IDENTIFIER}
```.

line 1:7 extraneous input ' ' expecting {'module', 'open', 'requires', 'exports', 'opens', 'to', 'uses', 'provides', 'with', 'transitive', 'var', 'yield', 'record', 'sealed', 'permits', IDENTIFIER} is a parse error. You're input isn't parsing for some reason. Unfortunately, the error reporting/recovery can be "opaque." Try commenting out lines using /* ... */ or // ... to find what does parse, and reintroduce what is not working little by little.

It seems that it is an issue of the  org.example.demo, if it is at the top of the file and does not have any comments above it, it cannot parse it. It is a problem with the
compilationUnit,packageDeclaration and module declaration rules, will try to add a whitespace token and see if that works. It is looking for a module instead of a package as it should.

For people that come across this, the mistake was using BufferedTokenStream.

You mean it's faster by using the unbuffered token stream?

No, that using BufferedToken stream does not work, as it processes code in chunks and it seems like it cannot parse properly this specific grammar.

The problem is that BufferedTokenStream.LT() returns off-channel tokens, whereas CommonTokenStream.LT() ignores off-channel tokens. This class extends BufferedTokenStream with functionality to filter token streams to tokens on a particular channel. This is exactly why you don't use it for the grammars in grammars-g4.
